# OS X Yosemite Developer Preview 2 does not show up in Mac App Store

Tags: macos, download, mac-app-store, osx-yosemite

I installed OS X 10.10 Yosemite build `14A238x` on Thunderbolt SSD / MacBook Air. A few days ago, Developer Preview 2 was released by Apple with the build number `14A261i` and it should be updated via the Mac AppStore. But it is not showing up for me.

Is there a hidden cache I can purge or any other way to persuade my Mac to obtain that update?

Comment: I've been experiencing the same problem. When I try to view the original Yosemite, I get an error that the product is not available on the Canadian store. I would assume, from this information, that either the new version is not available for Non-US users, or that the updates have a slight delay between the release of it for US users, and the release of it for other stores. If this is the case, then the update should become available soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to add that I was experiencing this same issue.

I tried reinstalling, enabling debug mode within app store and clearing the cookies/kickstarting update options, etc. to no avail.

As a last ditch effort, I created a new user on the system.  After entering my apple id information when logging in for the first time on the new account, I opened up the app store again and then finally saw the 1.0 update (developer preview 2) available.

Comment: This didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the connection you have to wait a specific threshold of minutes. After that the Mac AppStore displays the new update. And if you have an old OS X 10.9 server with enabled caching service on your network: Switch the network or temporarily disable that caching service.

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble using updates on the Mac App store on my first install. I reinstalled Yosemite (redownloaded via App Store) and just ran the installer again.
When it was done, all the updates showed up..